# In what order does tensorflow::Tensor's flat method return the data?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Let's say I create a tensor with the following dimensions

```
[num_tracks,num_frames,height,width,num_channels]

 *output = tensorflow::Tensor(tensorflow::DataType::DT_UINT8,
                               {4, 11, 128, 128, 3});
```

And I then return the data with the flat method.

```
auto data = output->flat<uint8>().data();
```

In what order will the data be returned if I iterate through the flattened data with
++data?

Will it be

```
[(track1, frame1, row1,column1,channel1), (...,channel2), (...,channel3),(...,column2,channel1)]
```

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#flat) it doesn't describe the order:

> These methods allow you to access the data with the dimensions and sizes of your choice. You do not need to know the number of dimensions of the Tensor to call them. However, they CHECK that the type matches and the dimensions requested creates an Eigen::Tensor with the same number of elements as the tensor.

```
    typedef float T;
    Tensor my_ten(...built with Shape{planes: 4, rows: 3, cols: 5}...);
    // 1D Eigen::Tensor, size 60:
    auto flat = my_ten.flat();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in TF sources the file `tf_tensor.h` which contains the following sentences:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// TF_Tensor holds a multi-dimensional array of elements of a single data type.
// For all types other than TF_STRING, the data buffer stores elements
// in row major order.  E.g. if data is treated as a vector of TF_DataType:
//
//   element 0:   index (0, ..., 0)
//   element 1:   index (0, ..., 1)
//   ...
```

flattened data of TF's tensor behaves like multi-dimensional arrays in C - when you go over a tensor the indices are being changed from right to the left. Suppose you have 2D array with dims 2x2, the order is: [0][0], [0][1], [1][0], [1][1].

[Here you have my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526083/tensorflow-c-api-problem-with-the-input-tensor/67530084#67530084) which describes how to create a method accessing 3D tensor when you have its pointer to flattened data.